# Does entity really can belong to only one aggregate?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I am learning DDD and just faced a problem that I can't solve.
Assume we have following domain:

```
public class Hotel : AggregateRoot {
    public List<Room> Rooms { get; private set; }
}

public class Room : Entity {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

and now we want to model RoomReservations.

```
public class RoomReservationRecord : Aggregate {
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public Room Room { get; set; } // <- this is problem
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
}
```

as clearly visible, 2 aggregates contains (share) single entity. It makes sense from business perspective, however from DDD perspective, it looks like 2 aggregates share the same entity.

1. Is this approach correct, or it violates "Entity can be part of single Aggregate" rule?
2. Or is there better (obvious way) to model such requirement?

Comment: Such issues strongly suggest that you didn't correctly identify the aggregate roots. Question here is: Is Hotel really an aggregate root? Or shouldn't the RoomReservationRecord be an aggregate? Or maybe `Room` just isn't an entity at all and just a value type. Also a aggregate can reference other aggregate, but only by its identifier (i.e. `RoomId` rather than `Room` on your referencing aggregate)

Comment: I had same thoughts, but then I realized that room can't exists without hotel. So making room Aggregate itself doesn't feel right IMHO. Room as a VO also doesn't feel right, because in real life rooms are independent entities. They can be identified by unique number, another identical rooms isn't the same one. I can make room an aggregate as well, but it makes risk that room will be without Hotel, unless we introduce Parent reference... which is pretty cool idea tbh

Comment: Right, but for a room reservation all that matter is the room number and maybe the hotel (if there are multiple hotels), which can be very well expressed as value type. A value type is identified by its values, so hotel+room number is pretty much unique to identify it. Why do you think you need a whole room entity for your `RoomReservationRecord` aggregate, when all you need is an association to the room

Comment: Because Room is an entity. When getting RoomReservation record, the whole point of DDD is to have a Room object within, not it's ID. It will still work with IDs, but IMHO the OOP and DDD is about to have a graph of objects in memory.

Comment: Anyway, article arguing against keeping IDs in entities https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/12/27/dont-use-ids-domain-entities/

Comment: _When getting RoomReservation record, the whole point of DDD is to have a Room object within_ not really correct. The point of aggregate roots is to act as transaction boundary, that within an aggregate is done in a single transaction. And a room being an entity of RoomReservation just doesn't make sense, because a `Room` can exist without an `RoomReservation`, so having it an entity of `RoomReservation` is just plain wrong. How ever `Room` can't exist without a `Hotel`, so that sounds more like the proper aggregate and why the ID on reservation just makes more sense.

Comment: @Tseng said it really well. Updating your question with details on the behavior you need will help us suggest models too. The point I was trying to make in my answer is that different models are suited to different behaviors. The points about transaction boundaries and what can exist on it's own were excellent points.

Answer (score 3):

I will try to point out a few things but at the end of the day this is a modeling exercise and often there are compromises to be made.

**Invariants** - A big part (probably the primary) of why you would group objects in an object graph is to make sure that certain rules are enforced. So if it was a business rule that NO ROOM CAN EVER BE DOUBLE BOOKED, then `Hotel` would probably be an aggregate root with rooms and reservations as entities on it.

Something like this... but this has some drawbacks...

EG.

```
class Hotel
{
    //members (eg. Rooms and Reservations) ...
    public Hotel(string name, ICollection<Room> rooms)
    {
        //...
    }

    bool TryMakeReservation(Reservation reservation)
    { 
        // if booked already return false
        return true;
    }
}

class Room
{
    //members ...
    public Room(int number, bool isBooked)
    {
        //..
    }
}

class Reservation  {
    public string CustomerName { get; private set; }
    public int RoomNumber { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; private set; }

    Reservation(Parameters)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

> NOTE: To use this model you would need to lock the hotel down each time you make a booking!

This might not be acceptable for a busy hotel. There are ways around this like reserving it for 5 minutes before automatically releasing it unless a reservation is confirmed. Or storing a list of events and if 2 reservations for the same room exist over the same period without a checkout event, kick off a process to notify someone to deal with the double booking.

**Contexts** - it might be that the list of rooms and the actual bookings are in separate domains. Think about how often bookings are done from multiple sources like AirBnb, Booking.com, hotel website, and/or at the counter in person or over the phone. It might not make sense for bookings and the persistence of available rooms to be in the same domain. What about cleaning schedules. A room needs to be cleaned before it is available but is this really handled in the Booking context?

**Performance** - as mentioned, sometimes the model we want just isn't possible because of the physics of getting that amount of data queried from a datastore. Users, Product Owners et.c tend not to care how clean your model is if it affects performance too much.

**Repositories** - following on from the above point, since an aggregate should be a consistent type (ie. data in it should never be in an incorrect state) then when you fetch your aggregate it should be consistent. If `Hotel` has a repository but contains a room, and `Room` is an aggregate root and has its own repository, and repositories are calling repositories, I would say you are failing at scaling complexity. The main point of DDD is giving a set of patterns and practices that help you deal with complexity. If by applying DDD principles you increased the complexity by a step that is never capitalized by the future smaller steps in complexity as new features are added, then DDD was probably not the right tool to use at that point in the project.

To speak to the linked article on Ids. Just not using primitive types can mitigate a lot of the problems here. Focusing on finding `Value Objects` can give a lot of clarity and really help express your domain. Even if you don't use DDD it is a valuable practice, which is why [I wrote a series on them without ever mentioning Value Objects... I think](https://devonburriss.me/honest-arguments/).

I hope this helped. DDD, more than even FP to me I guess, has so many super valuable ideas in it that help create maintainable code that scales to requirements. Better than that it has a focus on soft elements outside the code like collaboration and shared a language that brings even more value but they are just guidelines that need to be applied because you want a certain gain (and are willing to pay any incurred costs). They are not rules to apply and very seldom is it just a wrong and right path.

Comment: So in my example RoomReservation is a different bounded context? If 'yes' it means that these entities (Hotel and Room vs RoomReservation) shouldn't be aware of each other? And going further to modelling persistance (relational DB), the RoomReservations table shouldn't have FK to Rooms table?

Comment: It completely depends on the problem. My point was more that certain words, like `Room`, could show up in multiple contexts. Some would go fetch from another context, some may have a contained idea (unlikely). The relationships depend on what rules need to be enforced, not what relationship you think entities should have or what should be an Aggregate Root or not.